# Passing Value to parameter in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have a list of value which is more than 500, and every time I have to pass those value to the below stored procedure. Will it be possible to call those value dynamically?

```
RDBMS: SQL Server 2014
```

small set of @value example below.

```
    declare @valuetable table
(
value varchar(50)
)

insert @valuetable

select video union
select audio union
select hayward union
select abott union
select gsk
```

Code:

```
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(24) SET @value = 'video'     
DECLARE @DAYS INT SET @DAYS = -30               


SELECT * INTO #XTP1 FROM (                  
SELECT DISTINCT 'START' AS DTT, DATEADD(D,@DAYS,DATEACTIONED) AS DT FROM NEWREPORTS
WHERE value = @value                        
UNION                           
SELECT DISTINCT 'CHANGE' AS DTT, DATEACTIONED AS DT FROM NEWREPORTS
WHERE value = @value                        
)r
```

Thanks

Comment: use `in` query for this

Comment: @chiragsatapara: but i want to pass value one at a time, and save the output in excel

Comment: then you have to call this api in for loop from the backend.

Comment: Procedural code like stored procedures is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @chiragsatapara: i am not very sure whether cursor would give better performance. as value may increase day by day

Comment: @marc_s: sorry Marc: sql 2014

Comment: Again **SQL** is just the **query language** - so **SQL 2014** means the 2014 edition of the SQL language standard - which doesn't exist. I'm assuming you say **SQL** and you really mean **SQL Server** - the actual, concrete **RDBMS product** by Microsoft - then please use **SQL Server** to be clear and precise

Comment: @user3751360, cursor is the one of the option you have available but it also give you the same result which you fetch from the in query , For cursor you have to create temp table for all the list which you have and then you have to insert values in those temp tables and return values from that temp tables , and this was not an good practice

Comment: Any hint techie ?

Comment: Passing one by one (and retrieving the output to store in Excel one by one) is very inefficient.  If you added a column to hold the '@value' variable in your temp table (assuming the '@value' variable is unique), you would then be able to pass all the variables at once (IN, Table Type or XML parameter as best suits) and then retrieve all the answers at once.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock: Please give small example.

Comment: To give a proper example I need to know the code that is calling this procedure and the code that is then storing in Excel.  Are you doing all this, for example in VBA?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock: as of now the code is manually executing passing the variable and copying the output
to excel. i am trying to automate the thing , for saving to excel using SSRS

Comment: So where is the list of variables? In a table?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock: Yes

Comment: @JonathanWillcock:  Question edited to show example.

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do is to add one column to #XTP1 to store the value name.  Then you can do:

```
declare @valuetable table
(
value varchar(50)
)

insert @valuetable

select video union
select audio union
select hayward union
select abott union
select gsk

SELECT * INTO #XTP1 FROM (                  
SELECT DISTINCT v.value, 'START' AS DTT, DATEADD(D,@DAYS,DATEACTIONED) AS DT
FROM NEWREPORTS n INNER JOIN @valuetable v ON n.value = v.value                        
UNION                           
SELECT DISTINCT v.value, 'CHANGE' AS DTT, DATEACTIONED AS DT 
FROM NEWREPORTS n INNER JOIN @valuetable v ON n.value = v.value
)r
```

Now you can retrieve everything from #XTP1 in one go.  You will probably want to include "value" in your ORDER BY.

Comment: oh! No Permission to change table structure.

Comment: Do you have permission to create a table?  If so, then create a new one!

Comment: i can create a new table,but there is a ETL job which populated old table every time.

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand why this is a problem.  If you create a new table just for your use in this stored procedure, how is it affected by anything else?

Comment: when i create new table, i have to create it every time whenever old table populate with
new data.

Comment: Why?  Sorry but I really cannot help you further.  You are introducing elements and requirements that have nothing to do with your original question.  No-one here has a crystal ball.  Go away, study your problem and if you can't fix it, come back and ask a new question, with all relevant facts, sample data, table create scripts and desired output!